# Why don't the variables matter for my objective function?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

right now I am dealing with a topic from machine learning, **binary classification**. In my lecture notes we have a minimization problem:

$$ min_{w,b}|\{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\colon sign(w^Tx_i - b) = y_i\}| $$ and $$y_i\in\{1,-1\}$$

Now they argue that it isn't a good idea to solve this optimization problem since the direction and offset in $(w,b)$ doesn't matter for the objective function. Can someone clarify what is meant by the this? I mean of course the objective function is dependent on $(w,b)$?

Comment: For context, can you describe what they go on to do after mentioning this? Do they solve an alternative optimization problem instead?

Comment: I think I know what they meant now. They wanted to state that this optimization problem is to some degree invariant to change in w or b so that one doesn't necessarily get the best classifier from solving this problem.